# sudo apt-get update && upgrade runs on root, but not with sudo as normal user

Tags: upgrade, updates, sudo, root

Not much else detail to add. Latest release of Parrot OS, I'm curious why I could only get my update && upgrade to run as the root user, when AFAIK using sudo as my normal privilege user should have accomplished the same task.

The error I got was

> Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Thanks for your time as always :)

Comment: Try as separate commands:  sudo apt-get update , allow it to finish to a command prompt.  Then sudo apt-get upgrade and allow this to finish. I find this works better.

Answer (score 3):

You did not state your exact commands. Maybe they were

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

This (conditionally) runs `apt-get upgrade` without `sudo`. Then it fails because of insufficient permissions.

One way to deal with this is to run `apt-get upgrade` with its own `sudo`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

There is another way. `&&` belongs to the shell syntax. You can run two (in general: many) commands ("chained" with `&&`, `||` or `|`, or separated with `;`, `&`, or in separate lines) with a *single* invocation of `sudo`, if you explicitly run a shell with `sudo`. Example:

```
sudo sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get upgrade'
```